# Promo code for particular SKU

Tags: coupon, coupon-codes, price-rules, magento1.9.2.3

[image]

I am unable to put a conditional promo code for `SKU`. While I am selecting the `SKU` attribute it's showing **"is assigned"** or **"not Assigned"** instead of putting a particularity `SKU` code. Can anybody help to figure out this?

Comment: when I do it, it apply the promo codes on all SKUs in the cart, not just the one specified. Did you know why ? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Go to conditions tab and add your conditions under there. Select SKU from under Product Attribute and provide your sku
[image]

Comment: can you please tell me from where you have this SKU option in condition. I need this SKU option in my conditions.

Comment: When you click on plus button, select first option "product attribute combination" then select SKU. SKU should have "Use for Promo Rule Conditions" value set to "Yes" for this to work.

Answer (score 0):

For this please use go to **Conditions** tab and select **Product attribute combination** then you can set sku is and add sku which you want.

Answer (score 0):

Create a coupon:

1. Login to Admin
2. Go to `Promotions -> Shopping Cart Price Rules`
3. Click `Add New Rule`
4. Fill Rule Information

Set your conditions:

1. Click Conditions tab
2. Select Product attribute combination
3. Select `SKU`
4. Now, you will see `SKU is...`
5. Put your product `SKU` over there

Please **note that the SKU option may not show up by default**. Go to: `catalog -> attributes -> manage attributes`. Then search for the `SKU` attribute and set the drop down ‘Use for Promo Rule Conditions’ to and reindex if needed.

Answer (score 0):

The **SKU** attribute is not shown on the **promotions/rules** dropdown by default. You must enable it by doing this:

1. Head to Catalog > Attributes
2. Search for "SKU"
3. Set **"Use for Promo Rule Conditions"** to "Yes".